# Access apache2 virtualhost on oracle vm guest through nat?

Tags: virtualhost, nat, oracle, forwarding, apache2

my problem is the following: I have an Oracle VM with debian on it running apache2. This apache shall handle two webservers, therefore my conf looks like this:

```
< VirtualHost *:80 > (no spaces, serverfault just shows it wrong without)

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost     ServerName site1.hostpc.domain.com  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site1/error.log  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site1/access.log combined

< /Virtualhost >

< VirtualHost *:80 >

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost     ServerName site2.hostpc.domain.com  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site2/error.log  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site2/access.log combined

< /Virtualhost >
```

where hostpc is the name of the hostpc and domain.com is the local domain.

I forwarded Port 80 through NAT from the VM to the host pc (TCP, guest port 80 -> host port 80)

So here is my problem now: when I go to site1.hostpc.domain.com or site2.hostpc.domain.com in the VM, the different websites are shown perfectly, but when I try to open site1.hostpc.domain.com or site2.hostpc.domain.com on my host PC it can't resolve the DNS of the website. When I open hostpc.domain.com it shows site1 just fine, but no way to get site2.

I've tried a lot, but I cannot get it running.
(PS: I need to use NAT, Bridged network would disconnect my host PC from the network)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should forward port 80 from host machine to port 80 of virtual machine.
Make sure your host entries are correct

Comment: this is how my entries look like: http://i.epvpimg.com/Dnwic.png

Comment: Show me your host entry. It should be 192.168.120.30 your-site-name

Comment: oh, forgot to say it has to be reached by the whole local network, so a local host entry wouldn't work.

Comment: Try local host entry and see if it works. I think you have DNS problem

Comment: Try disable firewall on virtual machine

Comment: firewall looks like this: http://pastebin.com/L9KHce3h so it should be disabled, lokal host entry does work.

Comment: If local host entry works then the problem is in DNS server.

Comment: ok, and how to fix it? :(

Comment: Make local host entry to all the computers in network.

Comment: or change the configuration in DNS server

Comment: i've now set up another vm that should function as a dnsserver, but port forwarding via nat doesn't work :( http://i.epvpimg.com/O9W2d.png , then i changed my dns server on windows to 192.168.120.130 but then nothing can be resolved anymore.. not the hosts entries on the dnsserver vm, not even google.com

Comment: allow not only TCP but also UDP

Comment: add extra dns server 8.8.8.8 . It will resolve google.com